# Does Django store the tables inside the 'models.py' files for each app in the same database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

Just to make it clearer: suppose I have a Django project that contains multiple apps.

Each one of those apps contains a 'models.py' file.

Each one of those 'models.py' files contains multiple Python classes; each class represents a Python table.

(If I said anything wrong, please correct me).

If what I said above is true, my question is: does Django save ALL of those tables (from multiple apps) in the same database? If yes, can you 'join' data from tables that belong to different apps?

I hope this makes sense. I have just started learning Django and following their official tutorial but I feel it skips a lot of these types of questions and I find myself copying stuff without understand too much how exactly it works so here I am.

Comment: Not per se, you can define a router to specify in what database what model should be stored.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, alright, I get that; but what about the default behaviour? Judging by your answer, I am guessing it saves everything in the same database. Am I correct in assuming that?

Comment: That being said, since you say you follow the official tutorial this likely means you still are following the absolute beginning, so there is not much to worry about that at this point.

Comment: by default it uses the database you define as `default` key in the `DATABASES` setting, but you can alter this with a router. It would also be odd that it would be different, since that would require each time defining the database *per* model? Usually storing models that refer each other are better stored in the same database, since that allows enforcing the foreign keys.